# Cookie secure with OAuth and weblogic

Tags: cookies, oauth, weblogic

I have implemented an authentication solution using OAuth.

Everything was ok, but I added the tag cookie-secure in my weblogic.xml file. Now the cookie is not set and the session is not created.

This is the code I added and that is causing the error.

```
<wls:session-descriptor>
    <wls:persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</wls:persistent-store-type>
    <wls:cookie-http-only>true</wls:cookie-http-only>
    <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
    <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>false</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
</wls:session-descriptor>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by enabling the ssl listen port on my server and in firewall. The cookie-secure and cookie-http-only flags are both set to true.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched tag values in your descriptor xml. The `cookie-secure` flag tells the Web browser to only send the cookie back over an HTTPS connection but you also set `cookie-http-only` to true... you need to change it to:

```
<wls:session-descriptor>
  <wls:persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</wls:persistent-store-type>
  <wls:cookie-http-only>false</wls:cookie-http-only>
  <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure>
  <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>false</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
</wls:session-descriptor>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e14308/securecookies.htm

Comment: Thanks. I have done that, but I couldn't get it working properly. I think weblogic should answer with a https, but it is responding with a http page.

Comment: If you wanted to try it, you can disable non-secure connections entirely to see what happens. In the admin console go to your server page and uncheck the `Listen Port Enabled` box.

Comment: Even disabling the non-secure listen port and enabling the secure, I still can't get a https connection. Is it necessary to set a certificate? Thanks for helping me.